# Automatically Change Source code with Version Control Metadata

Tags: svn, version-control

I am working with source files in C# and I want to add headers that are automatically changed when checked in. For example so the date of check-in shows in the file, and copyright etc.

Is there a way to add tags to the source so when checked in these automatically are created but as importantly some that are consistent between management systems (i.e. SVN, StarTeam etc) should we need to change management systems in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to add tags to the source so when checked in these automatically are created

Yes - svn:keywords in your case

> but as importantly some that are consistent between management systems

Not (in common) - different VCS uses different syntax and techiques for RCS-style keywords, some doesn't use at all (Git), but allow some emulation layer, some (Mercurial) can use and serve SVN-keywords, but require handwork etc...